# iOS: Getting location updates in background only when in a car

Tags: ios, core-location, background-process, core-motion

I'm looking for continuous, energy efficient way to track distance travelled using a car, in background. The end goal is to be able to calculate the amount of mileage, the user has travelled using a car.
I'm imagining this to work the same way "Do Not Disturb While Driving" works.

I'm thinking to gather significant location updates and to measure 
the distance between them using MapKit's route API. Also i would like to detect whenever the user has started moving with a car and then based on that to start/stop location updates.

Also just to mention - location accuracy is not important, because i don't need to calculate super precise distance, e.g I could afford to have 50-100km error on every few thousands km.

So far so good, however i'm not entirely sure whenever i'm taking the correct approach or i'm missing something. Also i haven't figured out how to use CoreMotion in background.

On the questions part:

1. I'm i on the right direction, by using combination of:

   - significant location updates
   - MapKit's route API
   - CoreMotion
2. Is there a way to receive notifications in background when the user has started/stopped to move with a car?
3. Is it possible to determine whenever a location update was taken when moving with a car?
4. Is it possible to associate a location update with past motion activities?
5. Any directions, in case i'm looking at this from a totally wrong perspective?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @CocaCola for reminding me to actually post my update here.

So I did a PoC where i was experimenting with significant locations, visits and core motion activities.

I've ended to a point where i was able to detect relatively good start and end locations of a driving journey.

The tricky part comes to calculate the distance, so i used MapKit to calculate the shortest driving route between the 2 points, considering the other pivot points reported during the journey. The issue with that was that the routes in the city were sometimes very inaccurate, especially if you circle around the same location twice or more.
As overall that technique would work pretty much accurate if you are tracking long journeys.

You can find the PoC app here: https://github.com/KoCMoHaBTa/AutoLog